# How to flatten a List?

Tags: dart

How can I easily flatten a `List` in Dart?

For example:

```dart
var a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [true, false, true]];
var b = [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', true, false, true];
```

How do I turn `a` into `b`, i.e. into a single `List` containing all those values?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The easiest way I know of is to use `Iterable.expand()` with an identity function. `expand()` takes each element of an Iterable, performs a function on it that returns an iterable (the "expand" part), and then concatenates the results. In other languages it may be known as flatMap.

So by using an identity function, expand will just concatenate the items. If you really want a List, then use `toList()`.

```dart
var a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [true, false, true]];
var flat = a.expand((i) => i).toList();
```

Comment: To handle more levels of nesting, I do this: Iterable flatten(Iterable iterable) => iterable.expand((e) => e is List ? flatten(e) : [e]);

Comment: FYI, Quiver.iterables includes a `concat()` connivence method which uses `expand` like this.

Answer (score 28):

With Dart 2.3 or later, you instead can use collection-`for` and the spread operator to easily flatten a list.  I personally find it to be more readable than using `Iterable.expand`:

```dart
List<T> flatten<T>(Iterable<Iterable<T>> list) =>
    [for (var sublist in list) ...sublist];

void main() {
  var a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [true, false, true]];
  var b = flatten(a);
  print(b); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, a, b, c, true, false, true] 
}
```

If there are nested lists that you need to recursively flatten, you could use:

```dart
List<T> flattenDeep<T>(Iterable<dynamic> list) => [
      for (var element in list)
        if (element is! Iterable) element else ...flattenDeep(element),
    ];

void main() {
  var a = [[1, [[2], 3]], [[['a']], 'b', 'c'], [true, false, [true]]];
  var b = flattenDeep(a);
  print(b) // Prints: [1, 2, 3, a, b, c, true, false, true] 
}
```

[`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) additionally now provides a [`flattened`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableIterableExtension/flattened.html) extension method that can flatten one level of nesting:

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [true, false, true]];
  var b = a.flattened.toList();
  print(b); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, a, b, c, true, false, true]
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there's a built-in method for that, but you can always reduce it to a single value:

```dart
var a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [true, false, true]];

var flatten = a.reduce([], (p, e) {
  p.addAll(e);
  return p;
});

print(flatten);
```

I wish `addAll()` would return the original list. Currently it returns nothing. If that were true, you could write a single liner: `a.reduce([], (p, e) => p.addAll(e))`.

Alternatively, you can just loop through the list and add:

```dart
var flatten = [];
a.forEach((e) => flatten.addAll(e));
```

Comment: You can write the single liner using cascades: a.reduce([], (p, e) => p..addAll(e))

Comment: @kai-sellgren , I have checked the Dart API page but the syntax and the example there(https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.8.0-dev.6.0/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) are not the same as the one you have used here(the initial empty list [] to be more specific). Isn't that a case of "fold" ?

Comment: Reduce method doesn't accept initializer value use `fold` instead.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this efficiently with a generator:

```
Iterable<T> flatten<T>(Iterable<Iterable<T>> items) sync* {
  for (var i in items) {
    yield* i;
  }
}

Iterable<X> flatMap<T,X>(Iterable<Iterable<T>> items, X Function(T) f) =>
  flatten(items).map(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

the solution with expand method fits good to satisfy this case :

```
expect(ListTools.getFlatList([[1],["hello",2],["test"]]),orderedEquals([1,"hello",2,"test"]));
```

But not for theses ones

```
expect(ListTools.getFlatList([[1],["hello",2,["foo",5]],["test"]]),orderedEquals([1,"hello",2,"foo",5,"test"]));
expect(ListTools.getFlatList([1,["hello",2],"test"]),orderedEquals([1,"hello",2,"test"]));
```

To satisfy theses test cases, you need something more recursive like the following function :

```
List getFlatList(List list) {
  List internalList = new List();
  list.forEach((e) {
    if (e is List) {
      internalList.addAll(getFlatList(e));
    } else {
      internalList.add(e);
    }
  });
  return internalList;
}
```

Best regards,

Sébastien

Answer (score 1):

You can try this recursive solution that allows single elements too and flatten the deeply nested lists.

```dart
List flatten(List arr) => 
  arr.fold([], (value, element) => 
   [
     ...value, 
     ...(element is List ? flatten(element) : [element])
   ]);
```