# How to flatten a List<Map> in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I flatten a List in Dart? just like flatMap.
For example:

```
var a = [{"a":1, "b":1}, {"b":2, "c":2}, {"d":4, "c":3}];
var b = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4};
```

How can I turn a to b into a single List?

Comment: Does this answer your question (from seven years ago!) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413248/how-to-flatten-a-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to flatten a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413248/how-to-flatten-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Dart's collection-`for` construct and spread operator to succinctly build a `Map` from the elements of your `List`:

```dart
var a = [
  {"a": 1, "b": 1},
  {"b": 2, "c": 2},
  {"d": 4, "c": 3},
];

var b = <String, int>{for (var map in a) ...map};
```

Comment: could you please explain the ...map part a bit. I did not understand how this is working 

Comment: `...map` uses Dart's spread operator.  When used with a `Map`, it expands to a series of key-value pairs (e.g. `{...{'a': 1}}` is equivalent to `{'a': 1}`).  Further reading: https://medium.com/dartlang/making-dart-a-better-language-for-ui-f1ccaf9f546c.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I turn a to b into a single List?

It's a bit confusing with your question. Right now, I'm assuming you want to turn a to b. In this case, you can do this:

```dart
var new_a = a.expand((map) => map.entries).toList();
print(new_a); 
// Output: [MapEntry(a: 1), MapEntry(b: 1), MapEntry(b: 2), MapEntry(c: 2), MapEntry(d: 4), MapEntry(c: 3)]

var b = Map.fromIterable(new_a, key: (v) => v.key, value: (v) => v.value);
print(b); 
// Output: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```