# how to convert Flutter List<List> to List

Tags: flutter, dart

// Here Is my Code

```
List data = [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]];
List requiredList = [1,1,1];
```

Comment: I believe this is a duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413248/how-to-flatten-a-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the second value of the elements in the first list as second list you can do this:

```
List requiredList = data.expand((e)=>[e[1]]).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through the `data` and add the item in index 1 into output.

```
void main() async {
  List data = [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]];
  List output = [];

  for(final d in data){
    output.add(d[1]);
  }

  print(output);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data contains lists, i.e to access data of list you have to pass index of list, i.e 0 1 2 etc.

```
List data = [[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]];
               ^     ^     ^
               |     |     |
               0     1     2
```

Above mentioned are index of each sub-list

So if you want to access data from sub-list, call the main list followed by index of sub-list and index number of elements of sub-list.

```
data[0][1]    //this will give an output of 1
 ^   ^  ^
 |.  |. |
 *. **. ***
```

*.   => list containing lists here

**    => Index of sub-list

*** => index of element in list

Check this video [here](https://youtu.be/rO5TMSMTs3o) to get more clarity of concept. I've attached a video related to python but same things apply in dart/flutter as well.